# What are the best practises AWS IoT thing registration process?

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, aws

What are the best practises AWS IoT thing registration process?

How can the process of making devices available to the users be streamlined? I need to know how can this be done in a viable way. Should the

1. devices need to pre-registered before handing them over to end-users or can they
2. be registered and authenticated after user sets ups the device for the very first time. It simply can't be done using the AWS IoT console if you have hundreds or thousands of devices.

I need to understand if bulk registration is done how can the [x.509 certifcates be replaced once they are expired after a year](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html#server-authentication-certs)? Is over the air update scenario applicable for this one?

> CA certificates have an expiration date after which they cannot be used to validate a server's certificate. CA certificates might have to be replaced before their expiration date.